# Тернарный оператор в JavaScript-функции

Tags: javascript, тернарный-оператор

Здравствуйте!

Результат кода - undefined. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно использовать тернарные операторы в JS-функциях и вообще можно ли их использовать таким образом?

```js
var f = function fact(x) {x <=1 ? 1 : x * fact(x-1)};
document.write(f(3));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы забыли вернуть из функции значение

```js
var f = function fact(x) { return x <= 1 ? 1 : x * fact(x-1)};
document.write(f(3));
```

Вариант в стиле шик-модерн:

```js
const f = x => x <= 1 ? 1 : x * f(x-1);
console.log(f(3));
```

Comment: Шик-модерн без поллитра не разберешь)

Answer (score 1):

[Тернарный оператор в JavaScript (?:)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80) - это оператор принимающий три операнда. Он часто используется в качестве укороченного варианта условного оператора `if`. Ваш код вполне рабочий, только функция ничего не возвращает, поэтому у вас `undefined`.

```js
var f = function fact(x) {
  return x <= 1 ? 1 : x * fact(x - 1)
};

document.write(f(3));
```

Можно еще так сделать ваш вариант кода, без переменной `f`:

```js
function fact(x) {
  return x <= 1 ? 1 : x * fact(x - 1)
};

document.write(fact(3));
```

Можно почитать:

- [Функции](https://learn.javascript.ru/function-basics#%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)
- [Условные операторы: if, '?'](https://learn.javascript.ru/ifelse)

Comment: Ваш ответ чрезвычайно полезен. )

Comment: @Cavy это очень хорошо, рад немного подсказать